# How can I create a meaningful test of a function which creates a Queueable which posts Announcements through the ConnectApi?

Tags: unit-test, connect-api, asyncapexjob

I have this method:

```
public Id doPostAlerts(List<Product2> productList){
    List<ConnectApi.AnnouncementInput> announcementInputList = new List<ConnectApi.AnnouncementInput>();
    for ( Product2 product : productList ){
        ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = this.createTextSegmentInput(product);
        ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = this.createMessageBodyInput(textSegmentInput);
        announcementInputList.add(this.createAnnouncementInput(messageBodyInput));
    }
    return System.enqueueJob(new AnnouncementQueueable(announcementInputList)); 
}
```

I would like to make an Apex Unit or Integration test which asserts that this what it is expected to do.

However:

1. `System.enqueueJob()` returns null during test.
2. Even executing the above method between `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` does not seem to add anything to the expected `CollaborationGroupFeed`.

Any ideas how I can make some useful assertions about the above code?